# unsigned int variable that increases++ the value for no apparent reason

Tags: c, variables, memory, ansi-c

I've a variable that increases it's value without any notice. It's behaviour can be modified by a simple printf() in some random parts of the code.

I attached my executable in gdb an got this:

```
101         graus[grau]++;
(gdb) print arestas
$7 = 5
(gdb) n
95      for (i = 1 ; i <= vertices ; i++) {
(gdb) print arestas
$8 = 6
```

And here is the code block:

```
unsigned grau;
unsigned graus[vertices-1];
memset(graus, 0, sizeof(graus));

for (i = 1 ; i <= vertices ; i++) {
    grau = 0;
    for (j = 1 ; j <= vertices ; j++) {
        if (getValueFromMatrix(matrix, i, j))
            grau++;
    }
    graus[grau]++;
}
```

Which makes no sense at since the "arestas" variable isn't even used in the loop!

The "arestas" variable is used before the loop and declared with this block of code:

```
matrix = createMatrix(vertices, vertices);
arestas = 0;
if (!(arestas = loadAdjacencyMatrixFromFile(file, matrix))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERRO: O arquivo fornecido não é valido\n");
    exit(arestas);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

PS: I don't know if the question was sufficiently clear, but if not please ask for the required information.

Comment: Are you sure you're not writing outside the bounds of `graus`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a memory overrun in the line

```
graus[grau]++;
```

because grau goes from 1 to vertices. You need to modify it to

```
graus[grau - 1]++;
```

Also graus should be declared with vertices places, not vertices - 1

```
unsigned graus[vertices];
```

Comment: Ermm... `graus[0u - 1]` if all `getValueFromMatrix() === false`?

Answer (score 0):

`grau` can be a value `0` up to `vertices`. Since you declare `unsigned graus[vertices-1]`, this will overflow into whatever is next on the stack, which seems to be `arestas` in your case.

If you got `vertices = 1`, `grau` will be either `0` or `1`, therefore `graus` needs to be able to contain 2 elements, therefore `unsigned graus[vertices+1];`

Fix the size of `graus` and you should be good.

However, @WhozCraig also raises an interesting question about the loop bounds. ;)